# Could not find fragment.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0)

Tags: mapbox

It gives an error when I sync the map box

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> Task :app:compileDebugSources
>   Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not find fragment.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/fragment/fragment/1.1.0/fragment-1.1.0.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
15 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 12 up-to-date
    enter code here

```
   implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.1.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.11.0'
```

Comment: Post your build file, it might be better to spot the config error from there.